# Facebook JavaScript API - Login failure in Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk

The below code is from the official Facebook developer pages, and works in FF and Safari, and sometimes in Chrome — but more often not in Chrome.

On Snow Leopard with the latest Chrome, I click the login button and see a little flicker as the FB login dialog opens and closes. If, in my FB account, I remove and re-add the app, I get asked for permissions, but the `auth.authResponseChange` event never seems to fire.

Does anyone know if this is a bug, or where I might find a solution that doesn't require me to manually poll the server?

Is this a product of Google+ vs. Facebook?!

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
            appId       : $APP_ID$,                    // App ID from the app dashboard
            channelUrl  : $channelUrl$,              // Channel file for x-domain comms
            status      : true,                     // Check Facebook Login status
            cookie      : true,
            oauth       : true,
            xfbml       : true                       // Look for social plugins on the page
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below
  // will be handled.
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    console.log('auth.authResponseChange fired');
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs.
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they
      // have logged in to the app.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so.
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login()
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook.
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful.
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to
  present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked.

  Learn more about options for the login button plugin:
  /docs/reference/plugins/login/ -->

  <!-- scope='publish_stream,read_stream' -->
<fb:login-button  show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Windows XP Chrome reports an error in FB JS SDK code about an http/https protocol mismatch — changing the FB 'connect' URI from '//' to 'https' made no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into chrome settings - advanced settings;  Under privacy click "content settings".  See if the "Block 3rd party cookies and site data" is checked.

I'm having a similar issue where in chrome the js-sdk will give me the momentary fb popup, but doesnt actually seem to log the user in or recognize the user being logged in/authorized.  In my case I think I've narrowed my issue down to that setting.

If you have it enabled, try disabling it to see if that fixes it for you...  although that's really just a diagnostic step, it's not a resolution since you would still have users who have that setting enabled.

I'm trying to determine the workaround if any.. possibly involving the use of fb login flow "for web" (ie not using their sdk and thereby potentially avoiding the use of 3rd-party cookies)

here's my post on my version of this issue...  [can facebook javascript/php SDK's "talk" to each other if 3rd-party cookies are disabled? facebook->getUser() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463528/can-facebook-javascript-php-sdks-talk-to-each-other-if-3rd-party-cookies-are)

Comment: My work-around was to provide my own button with the onClick event firing FB.login. I suspect it would all have been okay had everything been hosted on an hTTPS server, which is apparently now an FB requirement (as of Oct 1).