# can facebook javascript/php SDK's "talk" to each other if 3rd-party cookies are disabled? facebook->getUser() returns 0

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies

I'm building a site w/ the facebook javascript&php SDK's working together...  It's generally working well, but-- I found that for one test machine using chrome, when I execute FB login from the client/javascript side, the PHP sdk on the back-end would not recognize it --  the facebook::getUser() function returns 0

After a lot of head-scratching and googling to no avail,  I realized/noticed via chrome dev tools, that for the machines that were working I see cookies called "PHPSESSID" as well as "C_user" which contains my facebook uid, and other name/value pairs; Whereas on the non-working machine, I only see the "PHPSESSID". I then found/realized that chrome on the non-working machine had 3rd-party cookies disabled.

So that is apparently the problem..  I've done some more googling but I cant find a clear answer to whether there's a workaround or better approach.

Is it simply not possible to integrate js+php sdk's if the user/browser disables 3rd-party cookies?  How else might my PHP back-end code determine which facebook user I am dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked around this by providing a login link on the page using the php-SDK getLoginUrl() and having the users use that instead of doing a client-side call to the javascript login() function or using the facebook social/login plugin. It might run into drawbacks at some point, but for now this seems to work on machine(s) that have 3rd party-cookies disabled

Answer (score 1):

From the javascript, after login, you can write your own first party cookie that contains the user id of the logged in user.  If you need to, you can also include the access token, but I wouldn't recommend this for security reasons.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion..  I'm going to give it a try but I'm thinking it might not work. I'm starting to think it's the JS SDK itself (and/or my JS in general on the client side) that is unable to access the fb info/cookies when 3rd-party cookies are disabled.. in other words I don't have access to the user ID so I can't set a 1st party cookie. Perhaps if I use the facebook login flow "for web" instead of JS SDK I'll be able to get it and set 1st party cookie..